# Split text in lines ffmpeg based on font and text length

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

How can I calculate when to put a new line based on text length and font
using function drawText from ffmpeg.
For example if i have a long text that I want to place it at bottom in the video and it needs to take how much place it needs.

```
drawtext=enable='between(t,0,18)':fontfile=font_simple.ttf:text='Here 
is a veeeeeeery loooong long text so I must somehow split it in 
multiple lines': fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=1:shadowy=1: 
fontsize=25: x=(w-text_w)/1.07: y=30
```

Comment: drawtext filter can't do wrapping.

Comment: @Mulvya maybe there is other way  how to do it?

Comment: Check the subtitles filter.